# Modify the format of grid coordinates

Tags: qgis-3, coordinates, grids-graticules

I am producing maps using OSGB references. However, I am using a 500m square grid, not 1km square. I would like to show the grid reference in a 3 digit format, the final digit being in a smaller font than the first two digits, e.g. the Easting 63 showing as 630, with the 0 showing as a smaller font, the next Easting is 635 with the 5 in a smaller font, the next Easting as 640 and so on. I am clueless on scripts. Sorry. I have searched on this site and on Youtube but can't find what I'm looking for in a format I can understand. I have found a piece of code I can utilise to produce a three digit format, `left(right(@grid_number,5),2)`but can't work out how to make the last digit smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the 3rd number to a subscript.

The [ascii codes](https://altcodeunicode.com/alt-codes-math-symbols-superscript-subscript-numbers/) for sub-scripted numbers range from 8320 to 8329, so we can extract the 3rd number, add 8320 to it and transform this new value to a character.

Create a grid, edit its properties, show the coordinates using a custom format. Click the epsilon button beside it.

Enter the following function

```
left(@grid_number,2) || char(8320 + substr(@grid_number,3,1) )
```

It takes the grid coordinates and keeps the first 2 numbers, then it concatenates (`||`) the subscript.

The subscript is constructed by extracting 1 character from the 3rd position, adding 8320 to it and transforming this value in the a character.

[image]

Comment: To have more control over the sizing, one can also draw 2 grids. The first one would show the first 2 digits and the second one would be drawn with an offset, with no pen (i.e. no grid line) and a smaller font. It is a pain to align the sides and top/bottom though...

Comment: Nice answer. May I ask why did you paste a comment under your answer instead of extending the answer itself?

Comment: @Taras because the ratio `effort / community gain` isn't worth it for this alternative solution, so a comment is enough

Comment: I modified this slightly to give me the numbering I wanted: left(right(@grid_number,5),2) || char(8320 + substr(@grid_number,4,1) )